# Laravel : Using transformers return error League\\Fractal\\TransformerAbstract

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I am trying to return response data with transformers but it returns an error

> Type error: Argument 2 passed to App\Support\Response::collection() must be an instance of League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract, instance of App\Transformers\UserTransformer given,

In a login controller when I print `$user` it print data

```
[original:protected] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [email] => test@test.com
        [password] => $2y$10$fyORQUSfUpIhDjrIBD2TK.elGKwdzV10YOmLd9Goks3z52AUYi8mK
        [status] => Active
        [system_role] => User
        [parent_user_id] => 0
        [otp_verifiy_id] => 253526851
        [last_login] => Carbon\Carbon Object
            (
                [date] => 2018-04-24 15:49:22.659941
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => Asia/Calcutta
            )

        [remember_token] => eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vMTkyLjE2OC41LjE1ODo4MDAwL2FwaS9hdXRoL2xvZ2l
        [created_at] => 2018-04-20 14:47:27
        [updated_at] => 2018-04-24 15:49:22
    )
```

After that I transform `$user` to `UserTransformer`

```
print_r($user);die; // above data
return $this->response->collection($user, new UserTransformer);
```

In my `UserTransformer` code look like

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Transformers;

 use App\User;
 use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;

 class UserTransformer {

  public function transform(User $user) {

      print_r($user);die;

}
}
```

On a `UserTransformer` when i print `$user` it returns error.What am i doing wrong.?

Comment: did u find the answer?

Comment: @AdamKozlowski yes

Comment: what was the solution?

Comment: `return (new UserTransformer)->transform($user)` collection not working and do not know why.

Answer (score 0):

Error is here:

```
return $this->response->collection($user, new UserTransformer);
```

The `new UserTransformer` is instance of `App\Transformers\UserTransformer`, but is should be instance of`League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract`

Are you sure that class `UserTransformer` should not implement any Interface?

Comment: Are you sure that class UserTransformer should not implement any Interface? Check in documentation of that class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend `TransformerAbstract` in your `UserTransformer` class:

```
class UserTransformer extends TransformerAbstract {

  public function transform(User $user) {

      print_r($user);die;

}
```